# AVD is not working properly

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create a android application in eclipse .When i am running the application it is showing

```
[2013-06-26 11:14:41 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-26 11:14:41 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-26 11:14:41 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-26 11:14:41 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Test'
[2013-06-26 11:14:41 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test'
[2013-06-26 11:14:50 - FirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-26 11:14:50 - FirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-26 11:16:24 - FirstApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-26 11:16:24 - FirstApp] Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-26 11:16:25 - FirstApp] Installing FirstApp.apk...
[2013-06-26 11:18:30 - FirstApp] Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-06-26 11:18:30 - FirstApp] (null)
[2013-06-26 11:18:30 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Firtsly uninstall the previous version of the application on emulator, then retry.

Comment: delete the existing AVD emuator, create a new one and then check..

Comment: Increase the AVD Connection timeout to something like 20000ms..
Windows-Preferences-Android-DDMS-"ADB connection timeout".

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue once and one of the following should work for you:-

- Restart the virtual device with the option Wipe User Data checked and then run the app. That works for me,
- Simply restart the device and check,
- Restart the device after changing the VM heap size.

If restarting the device doesn't work, try increasing the upload timeout to something really huge like 20000 ms. It's at Window → Preferences → Android → DDMS → "ADB connection time out (ms)".

Answer (score 1):

Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` code as well. I think u didn't placed the below code for Activity to be launched.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

If any `logcat` errors/warnings present, please post them as well. So, that we can help much better.

Comment: I am new In Android Development..And my AndroidManifest.xml code is :  <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Code looks good. I think emulator is not installed properly.Try to delete and create a new AVD and run the application after AVD launch is successful....

Comment: [2013-06-26 10:29:27 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 11

Comment: Avadhani Will u please suggest me how to setup android properly and create a sample application that will display Hello or some thing else

Comment: This shows that you are closing emulator during installation. Please try to reset `adb` by navigating to DDMS perspective, `Devices` tab and click the down arrow on top right corner. click `Reset adb`. Now install AVD again. Now it should work.

Comment: [2013-06-26 11:47:48 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-26 11:47:48 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD'
[2013-06-26 11:47:48 - FirstApp] Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-26 11:47:58 - FirstApp] Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2013-06-26 11:47:58 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!

Answer (score 0):

Try and format the log output so that its better readable. However, most likely you have something wrong in your Manifest. Check `adb logcat` (or the Logcat Tab in the DDMS perspective) while the app is installed. You should see some info there on what exactly android does not like with your application.